# Setting memory address of nodes in C++

Tags: c++, list, nodes

I seem to be having trouble understanding how to build a function that adds nodes into a linked list.

Thus far, i have this.

```
void StringList::add(string value){
StringNode *temp = new StringNode;
temp->data = value;
temp->next = NULL;

if(head==NULL){
    head = temp;
    temp = NULL;
}
```

I do not understand how I can set the memory address for the previous node each time i add to the list. Ideally, I would have given myself a tail node, however i was provided a driver and a header file which are to remain unchanged. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: If you add a node to the head of a list, you create a new node, set the `next` of the new node to be the current head of the list, and then move the `head` to point to your new node. Unless your list is empty, in which case the `next` is (usually) null.

Comment: What do you mean by "set the memory address for the previous node"?  You should never change addresses of the nodes, otherwise you're defeating the purpose of a linked list.  You should just be adjusting the links.

Comment: @user8891853  Show the list definition.

Comment: The best way to understand a linked list (or any other graph) is to draw the sucker out on a piece of paper. Step by step draw all of the modifications to th list to put it into the new configuration required by whatever operation you wish performed. Take notes on the steps required and convert those notes into code. When debugging, draw the node and follow your coded instructions. when you find yourself drawing something silly, you've found your bug and probably have a pretty good idea of what you need to do instead.

Comment: One of the most common faults is forgetting to null the final node. Consider adding a constructor to `StringNode` if you are allowed. This constructor should take a string value and a pointer to the next node. This way you are forced to set the next pointer to something. If you cannot add a constructor, make a helper function which creates the node, sets the value and next, and returns the pointer. The idea is to make it hard to make mistakes.

Comment: Please provide the definition of the node from your header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add your new node to the end of the list without having maintained a `tail`, you'll have to go through the whole list each time:

```
void StringList::add(string value){
  StringNode *temp = new StringNode;
  temp->data = value;
  temp->next = NULL;

  if(head==NULL){
     head = temp;
  }
  else {
     StringNode* last = head;
     while (last->next) {
       last=last->next;
     }
     last->next = temp;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve this is certainly to use an [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list):

```
list<string> l { "blue", "red", "white" }; 
l.push_back("yellow");
```

If you're obliged to use memory allocation for educational purpose, and you have to go through manual memory allocation, and things like that, you have to iterate through the list to find the last node:

```
...
if(head==NULL){
   ...
}
else {
    StringNode *i=head;  
    while (i->next)  // stops when the next element is NULL, so last element
        i = i->next;
    i->next = tmp;   // i is last element, so just connect to the new node
}
```